# Can't get activation URL after publishing a Closed Alpha Testing using email liste tester

Tags: android, google-play-console

After publishing a version of my application on Google Play Console, I don't receive the activation URL.

I've waited many day after publishing and no changes. On the top right of the "Application Version" Under my application name, it still noted "not published" ( I don't know if it matter ). But under my version name, it's noted Full deployment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jriWT.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Going to "Presence on the Play Store" > "Price and availability" > "Availability of the application" and turn to PUBLISHED fixed it.